# google maps zoom buttons not showing on narrow screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

Its quite tricky to see on the images as they look similar in size but when i re size my developer window in chrome to make my google map window change size the zoom buttons are lost.

[image]

[image]

Here is my CSS code

```
.mapContainer
{
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 25%; 
}
.mapContainer .mapCanvas
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

What have a i done wrong here?

**Edit**
Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/68jm4no9/

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: Show us some JS. Most of those options are set with the API.

Comment: I thought it would be quite hard to replicate but aparently it was easy:
http://jsfiddle.net/68jm4no9/

Drag the vertical sider to resize the google maps window

Comment: When height is too small it is normal that they disappear (see [Google Simple Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple) and try to resize you screen below 200px). Pls add to your fiddle `display:block;` and set an `height`, like `100px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is set by default for maps that are smaller than 200px. You can override that.

In the map options set `zoomControl: true`

EG

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: true
  });
}
```

Here's [the doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#Adding_Controls_to_the_Map).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the zoom icons are not re sizable. And when the height of map decreases to a limit, the zoom icons are removed as there isn't space for them to show.

So, add a static height to the map div.

```
.mapCanvas {

    height: 150px;
}
```

**Here:** http://jsfiddle.net/68jm4no9/7/

Or else you can use two custom buttons for zoom functionality and use JavaScript to get it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoomControl: true,
}
```

zoomControl will allow you to override size